# Renaming all '*.vhd' files to '*.wei', and the reverse

Tags: file-rename

What would a DOS '.bat' file or command look like to rename all files '*.vhd' in a folder and its subfolders to '*.wie', the number of files and the subfolder names not known in advance. 'RENAME' ('REN') has no option "do it in all subfolders, too".

The background to this question is that I am using CrashPlan (small business), and CrashPlan has a global non overridable exclusion of some extensions, among them '.vhd'. The '.vhd' files are VHDL source code files, VHDL being a primary language in FPGA/CPLD tools, e.g. Aldec Active-HDL, Xilinx ISE and Vivado, Synplicity Synplify. and several others. The global exclusion prevents my '.vhd' files from being backup-ed.
My trick is to rename all '*.vhd' to '*.wie' ('wie' being "next letter in the alphabet" of 'vhd')after running a FPGA/CPLD tool, and renaming the '*.wei'-s back to '*.vhd' before starting a tool. I can do it quite smoothly with 'Better File Rename', without knowing the number of files and the subfolder names in advance. But it would be convenient to have two '.bat' files doing this rename, and shortcuts to them on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895):

In `powershell`, after installing `rename`:

```
rename -n 's/\.vhd$/.wie/' ./*.vhd
```

Remove `-n` switch, aka *dry-run* when your attempts are satisfactory **to rename for real**.

There's a solution for windows in my link (install instructions)